# Using cURL to debug certifcate issue beween two servers

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, cert

Our company's server communicate with another company's server via HTTPS. New certificates have been installed on both servers. Because of some issue, communication is not happening. I want to use curl command to see the cert that our server presents and the cert that remote server is presenting. But I am not sure how to do this. Can someone give an example. Just to learn I tried curl -v --cert-status https://www.example.com but it does not tell me the status of example.com's cert

Comment: If I do this on google.com, I see a section that starts "Server certificate:" and below says "SSL certificate verify ok." with some details in between. What do you see and what are you expecting / hoping to see?